ListView.builder assigning removed data when item removed from provider (Riverpod)
I have a ListView.builder that is being populated via a watched Riverpod provider that contains a list of widgets. It is experiencing an issue in the UI where when you remove an item in the list that is above another item the values from the removed item are populated into the item below it in the list.
Assigning the provider to watch
final trainingGuns = ref.watch(trainingGunRepositoryProvider);

ListView.builder
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: trainingGuns.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return trainingGuns[index];
  },
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
)

Provider Repo
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'package:trainfactor/widgets/training_gun_entry_widget.dart';

part 'training_gun_repository.g.dart';

@riverpod
class TrainingGunRepository extends _$TrainingGunRepository {
  @override
  List<TrainingGunEntry> build() {
    return [];
  }

  void addTrainingGunEntry(TrainingGunEntry trainingGunEntry) {
    state = [...state, trainingGunEntry];

    printState(state);
  }

  void updateTrainingGunEntry(TrainingGunEntry trainingGunEntry) {
    state = state.map((entry) {
      if (entry.gunId == trainingGunEntry.gunId) {
        return trainingGunEntry;
      } else {
        return entry;
      }
    }).toList();

    printState(state);
  }

  void removeTrainingGunEntry(int gunId) {
    print('Removing entry with id: $gunId');
    state = state.where((entry) => entry.gunId != gunId).toList();
    printState(state);
  }

  void loadTrainingGunEntries(List<dynamic> guns) {
    state = guns
        .map((gun) => TrainingGunEntry(
              id: gun.id,
              gunId: gun.gunId,
              name: gun.gunName,
              image: gun.gunImage,
              caliber: gun.caliber,
              ammoId: gun.ammoId == 0 ? '' : gun.ammoId.toString(),
              roundsFired: gun.roundsFired,
              notes: gun.notes,
            ))
        .toList();
    printState(state);
  }
}

void printState(state) {
  print(state.map(
    (entry) =>
        "id: ${entry.id} - gun id: ${entry.gunId} - name: ${entry.name} - caliber: ${entry.caliber} - ammoId: ${entry.ammoId} - roundsFired: ${entry.roundsFired} - notes: ${entry.notes}",
  ));
}

I am printing my state on each change and the state always updates properly. Widgets are successfully added/removed from the list, and values within each widget are assigned properly.
Here is an example of state where one item has values for rounds fired and notes and another does not:
flutter: (id: 59 - gun id: 13 - name: Glock 43x - caliber: 9mm - ammoId: - roundsFired: 100 - notes: these are notes, id: 0 - gun id: 15 - name: Diamondback AR-15 - caliber: 5.56 - ammoId: - roundsFired: 0 - notes: )
And when removing a widget from the list the state updates correctly
flutter: (id: 0 - gun id: 15 - name: Diamondback AR-15 - caliber: 5.56 - ammoId: - roundsFired: 0 - notes: )
In the UI though the rounds fired and notes from the removed item shows for the remaining widget in the list.
I recorded a video and posted it on Dropbox showing the issue in the app — https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/bunyez4qryh444zm7ya1k/help.mp4?rlkey=kpd6oyygl7xw8a1or9hhyynej&dl=0
Below is the widget where the only items that are changing are the items not marked as final as they can change by user input or on load if it is an existing item.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:trainfactor/constants.dart';
import 'package:trainfactor/providers/ammo_repository.dart';
import 'package:trainfactor/providers/training_data_repository.dart';
import 'package:trainfactor/providers/training_gun_repository.dart';

class TrainingGunEntry extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  TrainingGunEntry({
    super.key,
    required this.id,
    required this.gunId,
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
    required this.caliber,
    this.ammoId = '',
    this.roundsFired = 0,
    this.notes = '',
  });

  final int id;
  final int gunId;
  final String name;
  final String image;
  final String caliber;
  String ammoId;
  int roundsFired;
  String notes;

  @override
  ConsumerState<TrainingGunEntry> createState() => _TrainingGunEntryState();
}

class _TrainingGunEntryState extends ConsumerState<TrainingGunEntry>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController _roundsFiredController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _notesController = TextEditingController();
  final ExpansionTileController _expansionTileController =
      ExpansionTileController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _roundsFiredController.text = widget.roundsFired.toString();
    _notesController.text = widget.notes;
  }

  imageWidget() {
    if (widget.image.isEmpty) {
      return const AssetImage('assets/images/default-gun.png');
    } else {
      return NetworkImage(widget.image);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final trainingGunsController =
        ref.read(trainingGunRepositoryProvider.notifier);
    final ammo = ref.watch(ammoRepositoryProvider);
    final trainingData = ref.watch(trainingDataRepositoryProvider);

    void updateTrainingGunEntry() {
      final trainingGunEntry = TrainingGunEntry(
        id: widget.id,
        gunId: widget.gunId,
        name: widget.name,
        image: widget.image,
        caliber: widget.caliber,
        ammoId: widget.ammoId,
        roundsFired: widget.roundsFired,
        notes: widget.notes,
      );
      trainingGunsController.updateTrainingGunEntry(trainingGunEntry);
    }

    bool isLiveFire = trainingData['type'] == 'live_fire';

    return Column(
      children: [
        ExpansionTile(
          backgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
          collapsedBackgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
          iconColor: kColorWhite,
          collapsedIconColor: kColorWhite,
          tilePadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 10),
          childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: kBorderRadius,
          ),
          collapsedShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: kBorderRadius,
          ),
          controller: _expansionTileController,
          title: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: kBorderRadius,
                    ),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                      maxHeight: 72,
                      maxWidth: 72,
                    ),
                    child: Image(
                      image: imageWidget(),
                      height: 72,
                      width: 72,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          widget.name,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: kColorWhite,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Visibility(
                  // Visibile if isLiveFire or ammo is not empty
                  visible: isLiveFire,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Ammo',
                        style: kLabelTextStyle.copyWith(
                          color: kColorWhite,
                          fontSize: 8,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 6),
                      Container(
                        height: 35,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: kColorWhite,
                            width: 2.0,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: kBorderRadius,
                        ),
                        child: ammo.when(
                          data: (ammos) {
                            return DropdownButton(
                              items: ammos
                                  .where(
                                      (ammo) => widget.caliber == ammo.caliber)
                                  .map(
                                    (ammo) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                      value: ammo.id.toString(),
                                      child: Text(
                                          "${ammo.name} - ${ammo.caliber}"),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                  .toList(),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  widget.ammoId = value.toString();
                                  updateTrainingGunEntry();
                                });
                              },
                              value: widget.ammoId == '' ? null : widget.ammoId,
                              hint: const Text(
                                'Select Ammo',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: kColorWhite,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                ),
                              ),
                              dropdownColor: kColorBlack,
                              underline: const SizedBox(),
                              icon: const SizedBox(),
                              isExpanded: true,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: kColorWhite,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          error: (error, trace) => const SizedBox(),
                          loading: () => const SizedBox(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Rounds Fired',
                  style: kLabelTextStyle.copyWith(
                    color: kColorWhite,
                    fontSize: 8,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 6),
                TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: kInputDecorationDark,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: kColorWhite,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: kColorWhite,
                  controller: _roundsFiredController,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        widget.roundsFired = 0;
                      } else {
                        widget.roundsFired = int.parse(value);
                      }

                      updateTrainingGunEntry();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Text(
                  'Notes',
                  style: kLabelTextStyle.copyWith(
                    color: kColorWhite,
                    fontSize: 8,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 6),
                TextField(
                  maxLines: 8,
                  decoration: kInputDecorationDark.copyWith(
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                      maxHeight: 95,
                      minHeight: 95,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: kColorWhite,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: kColorWhite,
                  controller: _notesController,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.notes = value.trim();
                      updateTrainingGunEntry();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                  child: Center(
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        trainingGunsController
                            .removeTrainingGunEntry(widget.gunId);
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Remove Gun',
                        style: kDeleteTextStyle,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
      ],
    );
  }
}


This was corrected by adding keys to the widgets in the list.
Using Keys in Flutter — https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc
